# Make ListView + SwipeRefreshLayout to get back to scroll after v21 update

Tags: android, android-listview, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

Prior to Android Support Library v21, when the user dragged a ListView with a SwipeRefreshLayout, the list itself scrolled down and a loading layout appeared: http://sdchang.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/001.png

Now, after the update, the "refreshing..." layout has changed. The list is fixed and a small white circle pops up. Can I make the ListView scroll down again?

Comment: You are saying when you are scrolling the list back to the top the swipe refresh layout is triggered?

Comment: Basically, he doesn't like the new style.  There is nothing wrong with customizing the way things work a bit, but I think you are better off leaving it as the expected behavior to be consistent with other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change how the new refresh animation works.

To make everything work back to normal, use the old [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f25dedc/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java) as custom layout class.